# Ocaml add index to every item of a collection

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I want to add a unique ID to every element in a collection (before output it as a JSON object).

A collection can be any set of items, as long as it has a `map` method implemented (`Array`, `List` and other custom collections such as trees comply with this requirement).

```
(** For a collection 'a t returns a collection of type (int, 'a) t *)
let add_indices_to_collection map collection =
  let index = ref (-1) in
  let add_index_to_element e =
    index := !index + 1 ;
    (!index, e)
  in
  map add_index_to_element collection
```

And I can invoke it later per example with :

```
 CollectionHelper.add_indices_to_collection NonBinaryTree.map my_tree
```

It seems a little bit clumsy to me, is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: My immediate thought is that you can abstract this out using a functor.